# POCO entity Fluent API versus Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1

I am coding our POCO entities in a **Domain** project in which I have no references to either `EntityFramework` or `DataAnnotations`. A second project, **DataAccess**, contains the data context and fluent configuration of entities.

Some entity properties are `IsRequired` or `HasMaxLength`. Developers using the Domain will not know what is required or if there is a maximum length of the property without Xml commented documentation. So, I've added documentation to the properties to convey the requirements.

The problem is, however, if a requirement changes I have to update the comments. This means that I'm updating 2 libraries - Domain and DataAccess.

I've been apprehensive in referencing DataAnnotations in the Domain; there are no attributes on my properties. These attributes would give a developer with access to the Domain entities knowledge of what is required or if there is a max length for a property.

Is there another way to convey property requirements for properties without using DataAnnotations on the entities or having to update the Xml comments on the entities?

Or, am I being unnecessarily thick-headed about adding the `DataAnnotation` reference to the Domain project?

Comment: This article maybe has a good advise for it http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorththeMapping/

Comment: My personal feeling is that it shouldn't be an issue to attach those kinds of annotations to your entity classes.  Things like column and table mappings are best left to the data access layer so that your entities are insulated from details that aren't really an intrinsic part of your model, but in my opinion annotations that specify requirements for the *contents* of your entities are perfectly appropriate.

Comment: I tend to be practical about these issues.  If an attribute is one that a developer using your domain must know about, then it belongs to the domain.  Don't be afraid to reference Data Annotations.   I personally can't imagine a scenario where referencing the DataAnnotations assembly would impede reusability.  It is a much better solution than manually updating comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be a good idea to leave your POCO entities without annotations and without including reference to EntityFramework.dll. Easier to create portable dll and reuse your model. That is, if you ever going to need it.

But as you said it makes it harder to have "auto documented" model. You could try with generating model diagram out of DbContext, there is a [power tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2013/03/03/generating-entity-data-model-diagram-from-ef-code-first-dbcontext.aspx) for that. Maybe that will be enough for your documentation needs. I tried it on a model with >200 entities and it worked ok. For the diagram generation it took cca 2min but after that it worked ok and was useful for "documentation" purposes.

Comment: Installed the power tools and it looks like it gives me the documentation needed. The portability of the Domain entities is paramount. Thanks!

Comment: The EF power tools created a nice Xml document but I cannot find anything to create a help file or standard documentation from the Xml. Any ideas? Sandcastle does not seem to provide a good solution since it seems to require a project or binary.